# changing the forecolor in array of dynamically created combobox based on item in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, combobox

I have to change the forecolor of 30 combobox**s**  created dynamically and forecolor schould based on the item value. As, I'm having dynamic array of combobox i cant do it so... please help me.

Code Sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
ComboBox[] cb = new ComboBox[28];

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 28; ii++)
    {
       cb[ii] = new ComboBox();
       cb[ii].Name = "cb"+ii.ToString();

       cb[ii].Items.Add("OK");
       cb[ii].Items.Add("NOT OK");

       if (cb[ii].Items.ToString().Equals("OK"))
       {
           cb[ii].ForeColor = Color.Black;
       }
       else
       {
           cb[ii].ForeColor = Color.Red;
       } 
   }
}


New code:
    private void ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Event Raised");

        ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (senderComboBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {

            if (senderComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                senderComboBox.Items.Add("");
                senderComboBox.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                senderComboBox.Items.Remove("");
            }
            else
            {
                senderComboBox.Items.Add("");
                senderComboBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                senderComboBox.Items.Remove("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: foreground color of an item in combobox?

Comment: Which exact problem do you have with this "dynamic array"?

Comment: @AseemGautam Yes... Forecolor property...

Comment: @JeffRSon : dynamic array containing combobox as its objects. cant achieve the property as ordinary static combobox to set the forecolor based on item value.

Comment: Explain this with some code. Show what doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffRSon : Added the code sample. please check it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @gzaxx and @JeffRSon Here is the working code,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ComboBox[] cb = new ComboBox[28];

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   for (int ii = 0; ii < 28; ii++)
   {


            cb[ii] = new ComboBox();
            cb[ii].Items.Add("OK");
            cb[ii].Items.Add("NOT OK");

            cb[ii].SelectedIndex = 0; 
            cb[ii].ForeColor = Color.Black;  
            cb[ii].SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

   }
}

private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
        if (cbx.Text == "OK")
        {
            cbx.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            cbx.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the color in SelectedIndexChanged, say:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
   if (cbx.Text == "OK")
   {
      cbx.ForeColor = Color.Black;
   }
   else
   {
      cbx.ForeColor = Color.Red;
   }

}
```

The sender is a reference to the affected ComboBox.

Comment: I cant write `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` for all the 28 comboboxes... Thats the problem...

Comment: Always use the same. If you create your dynamic ComboBox assign its event.

Comment: Didn't get you "whats meant by assigning events?" I tried your code. Cant get the change in color.

Comment: It is as easy as
`cb[ii] = new ComboBox();
 cb[ii].SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);`

Comment: Thanks a lot... The previous ` cb[ii].SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);` Worked...

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your `for`:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 28; ii++)
{
   cb[ii] = new ComboBox();
   cb[ii].Name = "cb"+ii.ToString();

   cb[ii].Items.Add("OK");
   cb[ii].Items.Add("NOT OK");

   cb[ii].SelectedIndex = 0;        //"OK" option will be selected
   cb[ii].ForeColor = Color.Black;  //set forecolor to black

   cb[ii].SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged;  
}
```

next add this event:

```
private void ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    if (senderComboBox.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        if (senderComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            cb[ii].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            cb[ii].ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

`SelectedIndexChanged` is fired always, whether index has been changed by user or by code. If you want to change fore color only when user changes selection use `SelectionChangeCommitted`

Comment: First thank you for the code. It works but a with a problem. The `SelectedIndexChanged` doesnt work when the index changed by code. thats not the problem. I have edited the code i did and the problem was, it always needs a messagebox so that only the color gets changed. please help me.